# Strange NullPointerException in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I think the following question is gonna be silly(I am just a beginner in coding) but i have been sitting on it for a long time and finally decided to put it up. I have a method as getName() at class level which access the string.xml file and gets an entry from there.

**CODE :**

```
public String getName()
    {
        String name = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside getName");
            String app_id = MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_id);
            System.out.println(app_id);
            fb = new Facebook(app_id);
            System.out.println("Before the JSON");
            String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
            System.out.println("Successful in fb.request");
            obj=Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
            System.out.println("Successful in parsejson");
            name = obj.optString("username");
} catch...
}
```

When i call the above method, it returns NullPointerException at

```
   String app_id = getString(R.string.app_id);
```

The funny and best part is that i have same exact line at the onCreate() method as below :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.postbutton);
        snap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_image_view);
        sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        **String app_id = getString(R.string.app_id);**
        fb = new Facebook(app_id);
        System.out.println("The app_id is " + app_id);
        String access_token = sp.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);
}
```

This doesn't throw any null pointer exception. My question is that why it throws the NullPointerException at method getName() alone. Does it have something to do with the scope of R ? I am totally lost here and feel really embarrassed to post such questions but also unable to accept the fact that its throwing me this dumb error. Any help will be insanely appreciated guys !!!!

**UPDATE :**

**Logcat :**

```
  12-26 17:24:07.330: W/dalvikvm(23184): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4118d438)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.facebook_integration/com.example.facebook_integration.SQLiteDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4954)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at com.example.facebook_integration.SQLiteDemoActivity.onCreate(SQLiteDemoActivity.java:33)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5252)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
12-26 17:24:07.330: E/AndroidRuntime(23184):    ... 11 more
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

**Strings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Facebook_Integration</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="app_id">594458613962731</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="title_activity_snap__image_view">Snap_ImageView</string>
    <string name="album_name">San_Pictures</string>
    <string name="title_activity_android_custom_gallery">AndroidCustomGalleryActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_full_screen">FullScreen</string>
    <string name="title_activity_sqlite_demo">SQLiteDemoActivity</string>

</resources>
```

**UPDATE 3 :**

As I am dealing with facebook i thought the issue was with creating the instance of Facebook object(fb) so I commented that line and tried again but it still says NullPointerException at

```
String app_id = MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_id);
```

If someone has dealt with a situation like this then please lemme know.

**UPDATE 4 :**

**Structure of MyApp :**

The following is my app's gist

1.Log into facebook.

2.Take a picture.

3.Store the username and the path of the picture taken in a database.

Initially my main activity has facebook image which would log me inside facebook and retrieve the username thereby setting it in a textview at the same main activity.
Secondly a camera button which would take me to the camera and take a picture.
Once the picture is taken, the third activity should display the username and the path where the picture is stored.(This is where I am unable to get the username again).

Comment: Just to be sure, can check if R.java has "app_id" under 'public static final class string'

Comment: It is inside "public static final class String" !! Thanks for consideration.

Comment: Are you calling getName from a broadcast receiver or a Service?

Comment: I am not using any broadcast receiver. I am just calling it usig java fashion. Classvariable.methodname() style.

Comment: Sudhee's answer, below, is probably correct (though hard to understand).  You are calling "getName" on an incompletely constructed object.  getString won't work until after onCreate has been called.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you should provide application or activity context to get resources value like below:

```
String app_id=youractivity.this.getString(R.string.app_name);
```

this way is very simple. Hope this help...

Comment: Will try this and get back to ya.

Comment: Sorry mate. No changes, the error still exists and drives me crazy. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @San Please debug your code and you know exactly whats wrong in your code line.

Comment: Another small issue in debugging is that my first activity logs into facebook and retrieves the username and sets it to a textview. So when i debug and click on the facebook button, it doesn't reach facebook and calls "source not found" but when i run it, it works fine.

Comment: @ManishPatel No,it's not solved yet but i will surely post my answer if get it. Appreciate your concern though.

Answer (score 1):

First of all must check that your **app_id** in ***strings.xml*** file is right.

And if it is then change

```
 String app_id = getResources().getString(R.string.app_id);
```

Comment: I have double checked the app_id in strings.xml, it is safe and sound. Tried that but no use. Thanks anyways. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

I found this happening to me with a broken layout. No need to be worry. I am trying my best to giving you the solution

**Solution**

Make sure that anything the **R.** links to is not broken. Fix all errors in your XML files. If anything in the ADKs are broken, R will not regenerate.

If you somehow hit something and created import android.R in your activity, remove it.
Run **Project -> Clean.** This will delete and regenerate R and BuildConfig.

Make sure **Project -> Build** Automatically is ticked. If not, build it manually via **Menu -> Project -> Build Project .**

Wait a few seconds for the errors to disappear.

If it doesn't work, delete everything inside the **/gen/** folder

If it still doesn't work, try right-clicking your **project -> Android Tools -> Fix** Project Properties.

Check your *.properties files (in the root folder of your app folder) and make sure that the links in there are not broken.

Right-click your **project > properties >** Android.

Look at the Project Build Target and Library sections on the right side of the page. Your Build Target should match the target in your AndroidManifest.xml. So if it's set to target 17 in AndroidManifest, make sure that the Target Name is Android 4.2. If your Library has an X under the reference, remove and re-add the library until there's a green tick. This might happen if you've moved a few files and folders around.

**What to do if R doesn't regenerate**

This usually happens when you have a broken xml file.

Check errors inside your XML files, mainly within the **/res/** folder

Common places are **/layout/** and **/values/** especially if you've changed one of them recently

Check **AndroidManifest.xml**, I find that often I change a string, and forget to change the string name from AndroidManifest.xml.

Check that Android SDK Build-tools is installed. **Window->Android SDK Manager->Tools->Android SDK Build-tools**

Make sure when you update the Android SDK Tools, you also update the Android SDK Platform-tools and Android ASK Build-tools. Build fails silently if they don't match.

If you can't find the issue, right click **/gen/ -> Restore from local history... -> tick R.java -> click Restore.** This doesn't solve the problem, but it will clear out the extra errors to make the problem easier to find.

Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: I cannot thank you enough pal. I have gone through each and every step of what you've given but still that idiotic issue exists. Thank you so much for taking the effort and enlightening me. Keep that spirit up.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know whats the problem exactly but i can provide you with a better solution

try saving this app id in shared preferences and then you can access it anytime anywhere.

or make a static string in any class (i always make a special class for all constants static variables) and then you can call this variable from anywhere anytime also :)

Comment: Its not the issue of saving or getting the data from any variable. Its error happening just because of string resuorce ID.

Comment: Thanks Tarek but i am trying to find a logical reason for this error. Of Course your idea is neat and perfect but why would this be happening without a solid reason !!

Comment: if you are using eclipse you can expect anything :D my friend once edited something in an xml file like you and ended up remaking the whole application from the start ... so my advice backup your project before doing any thing :)

Answer (score 0):

My revised answer based on updates:

I am afraid creation of activity is not just limited to creation of an Activity
Object.  It is followed by various initializations and setter calls, which
the Android system will do, which yields the complete context for the activity.
Ex: When your MainActivity is created by the Android system, the MainActivity 
object is created, followed by initializations which also include binding the 
object with the resources. 
When you create an MainActivity object inside your App, none of these initializations happen, hence, you cannot access resources (among many other things). This object
is not a true activity object in Android Sense.  It is just an uninitialized object
of MainActivity class.

In your case, string values from resources are accessible through-out the application,
in all  activities using the current activity context. You may probably want to use 
that.  If you have a need to share information between activities there are different
ways of achieving this as below:

1. pass the information back and forth using intents on
   startActivityForResult() 
       - preferred approach
2. Use a separate class with static members where you save information that can
   be accessed in other
   activities (be careful here, if you save information that    is
   pertinent to a activity, it will lead to crash, ex: if you save the
   reference    to a TextView in layout of activity1 and try to access
   it from activity2 with a     different layout, it will fail)
3. using preferences

Hope this clarifies.

---

To answer better, I need the full structure (not full code, just the structure).

However, I can make a guess as to what is happening.  I assume you have created a specific class which has the member function getName(), among others may be.  This is what I am assuming by looking at the way you are calling the getResources() (MainActivity.this.....).  I am afraid this wont work.  Android's objects are all inherited from Android base classes and hence have a context associated with them.  When you have a separate class with a member functions using Application context functions like getResources(), it wont work as it could potentially lead to a situation where the Android Application objects are not instantiated, ex: you create the an object of your non Android class and call the getResources(), what is the guarentee that Android App has been created then?  Similar problem occurs if you use getResources like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Resources res = this.getResources(); //you cannot use like this
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719570/getresource-error) for more

The solution to this is to ensure you call getResources() after the App is created, the first entry point where you can ensure this is onCreate() of your MainActivity.  Also,
if you do are using other classes that dont inherit from Android base classes, ensure the runtime context is passed.

Comment: I understand there are 3 activities.  Where is the getName() defined, in which class ?

Comment: getName() is defined at MainActivity and it is called at third activity. MainActivity is where my facebook details are given and the name is obtained. I have also tried setting the name(username got from facebook) to another string variable and returning it to the third activity but that returns null !! Weird eh !!

Comment: San, if you have defined getName() in class MainActivity, how are you able to access it from 3rd Activity ?  Are you passing object reference of MainActivity to 3rd Activity?  Otherwise you wont be able to do it unless getName is static.  Can  you provide structure of the code, ie., all class structures = variables, member function declarations for all activities without implementation.

Comment: I am calling getName() by using an object of MainActivity as MainActivity main_object = new MainActivity(); main_object.getName() and assigning it to a string variable. Java style !!

Answer (score 0):

Do this as follows.

```
public String getName(Context ctx)
    {
        String name = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside getName");
            **String app_id = ctx.getString(R.string.app_id);**
```

You don't need to call getResources. pass Context/ctx at the point of calling this method, If you are not calling this method from activity/service/Receiver. please save Context instance in static variable.